# Compile Error: Window does not contain definition for template, even though template is defined. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, controltemplate

I'm trying to switch the template for a datagrid based on certain conditionals, but even though I define a template, the program does not compile, saying my window doesn't contain a definition for said template.

XAML

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid" x:Name="myGrid">
            <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag" Binding="{Binding Tag}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

C#

```
if (mybool == true)
            scrollWin.gridMain.Template = scrollWin.myGrid;
```

This seemed like a "just restart Visual Studio" issue, but that didn't help. I don't get any errors before trying to run the program, hovering over "myGrid" shows that it recognizes it as a member of scrollWin. Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `ControlTemplate`? It's resource, isn't it? And what kind of element is `gridMain`?

Comment: I just put the Control Template inside the Datagrid who's template I want to change., which is gridMain.

Comment: Inside what element exactly?

Comment: Directly inside the datagrid, not style or resources or anything.                    






`<DataGrid Name="gridMain">
      <ControlTemplate Name=myGrid....etc`

Comment: That makes no sense. It should be defined as a resource. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ControlTemplate` should be defined as a *resource* with an `x:Key` instead of an `x:Name`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid" x:Key="myGrid">
```

If you then put in the `Resources` dictionary (`<Grid.Resources>` or whatever type `grdMain`is) of `gridMain`, you could get a reference to it like this:

```
scrollWin.gridMain.Template = scrollWin.gridMain.Resources["myGrid"] as ControlTemplate;
```

The definition of the template itself looks a bit odd but that's anothe issue.